# Não consigo trabalhar com uri(rotas) usando hosts virtuais

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost, host

Eu criei um host virtual usando o apache, o problema é que eu consigo acessar o site no meu "localhost" da seguinte forma:

```
site.com
```

Para acessar o meu site no localhost dessa forma eu fiz o seguinte no arquivo "/etc/hosts":

```
127.0.0.1 site.com
```

E fiz uma configuração no apache para para acessar o meu site no localhost, a configuração é a seguinte:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

O problema é que não consigo acessar as minhas rotas usando o host virtual do apache exemplo:

```
site.com/usuarios
site.com/v1.0/usuarios
```

Enfim não consigo acessar nenhuma rota(uri), como eu posso resolver isso ?

Tenho uma pasta com vários projetos fiz um .htaccess nela para não deixar ninguém ver minha estrutura de diretórios dessa forma:

.htaccess Pasta "Projeto":

```
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
```

Agora dentro dessa pasta projeto tenho uma outra pasta que se chama "site.com" que é o projeto que eu não consigo acessar nenhuma uri, dentro dela eu tenho uma pasta que se chama "public_html" que tem um outro arquivo .htaccess e um arquivo index.php, o arquivo .htaccess esta dessa forma:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Veja como é minha estrutura de diretórios:

```
projeto
   .htaccess
   site.com
       public_html
           .htaccess
```

Sei que o que eu aplico em um .htaccess nas pastas mais altas é aplicado também as subpasta, será que tem algo de errado no .haccess que foram criados nessas duas pastas ? ou é minha configuração de host virtual que está incorreta?

Comment: como está seu arquivo `.htaccess` ? Coloque ele na pergunta também.

Comment: Editei a pergunta coloquei como esta meu arquivo .htacces, e também coloquei minha estrutura de diretórios.

Comment: Dentro do diretório `site.com` tem o diretório `public_html`?

Comment: Tem sim me desculpe, vou editar a pergunta novamente, mas ja mudei a estrutura de diretórios.

Comment: verifique a permissões de acesso dos diretórios

Comment: da algum erro quando você acessa as URLs?

Comment: Sim da um erro: 404 Not Found, o mais engraçado é que fiz a mesma coisa no windows e não deu erro, vou mandar a permissões de pasta...

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 dev dev  313 Set 14 12:11 .htaccess, todos os demais arquivos inclusive minhas pastas estao com essa mesma permissão ai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que estava acontecendo é que eu não permiti que o arquivo .htaccess no diretório public_html fizesse override, então acrescentei algumas configurações no meu host virtual do apache para permitir isso, veja a nova configuração do host virtual:

```
ServerName 127.0.1.1
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@test.com
        ServerName site.com
        ServerAlias www.site.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site.com/public_html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        #Foi necessario acresentar essas configuracoes
        #pois eu nao estava conseguindo acessar uris(rotas)
        #de todas as configuracoes a mais importante
        #e que resolvel meu problema foi a AllowOverride all
        <Directory /var/www/site.com/public_html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Da forma que estava antes é como se o arquivo .htaccess nem existisse.

Answer (score 1):

O problema esta no `.htaccess` do diretório `Projeto` a linha `IndexIgnore *` desabilita a listagem do diretório.

**Update**

Conforme informado por comentários. Edite o `.htaccess` do diretório `public_html` e deixe ele desse jeito, assim que eu poder eu edito a resposta, explicando certo parte por parte do código.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Já desabilitei e não deu certo.

Comment: Mas fiz isso aqui e deu certo: site.com/index.php/v1.0/usuarios , porque funciona assim ? tem como tirar esse index.php da url ?

Comment: Eu quero acessar dessa forma: site.com/v1.0/usuarios

Comment: vou atualizar a resposta, estou no celular rs.

Comment: Tem algo estranho tentei mudar o meu .htaccess da pasta public_html deixei igual ao seu não deu certo, troquei por vários outros que achei na internet e não deu certo, coloquei até um que vi na documentação do slim php que é o framework que estou usando e não deu certo, tem algo muito estranho nisso.